# Laravel QueryBuilder to Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-query-builder

## **Updated:**

I'm almost getting my result, I'd just like to filter the "current" student I'm looking for

My updated model:

```php
// Student.php
public function enrolled()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classroom', 'inscribed_students')
    ->with('enrolled_steps.student_process')
    ->whereRaw('start_at >= curdate()');
}

// Classroom.php
public function enrolled_steps()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\InscribedStudent');
}

// InscribedStudent.php
public function student_process()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\StudentSelectionProcess');
}
```

My output json:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "This is a Student",
  "email": "dborer@example.org",
  "enrolled": [
    {
      "id": 31,
      "name": "This is a Classroom",
      "shift": "Morning",
      "enrolled_steps: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "student_id": 1,
          "classroom_id": 1,
          "student_process": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "status": "Approved"   
            } 
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "student_id": 2,
          "classroom_id": 1,
          "student_process": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "status": "Approved"   
            } 
          ]
        },  
      ] 
    }
  ]
}
```

The current problem is the **enrolled_steps** are return a array, but im filter one student, how can I fix it to get only my current student?

My expected output:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "This is a Student",
  "email": "dborer@example.org",
  "enrolled": [
    {
      "id": 31,
      "name": "This is a Classroom",
      "shift": "Morning",
      "enrolled_steps: {
        "id": 1,
        "student_id": 1,
        "classroom_id": 1,
        "student_process": [
          {
            "id": 1,
            "status": "Approved"   
          } 
        ]
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

## **Question:**

My problem is I have to do multiple/hard relationship to show info about student.

```
+--------------------+
| Student            | 
+--------------------+
| id                 | 
| name               |
| email              |  
+--------------------+
```

```
+--------------------+
| Classroom          | 
+--------------------+
| id                 | 
| name               |     
| shift              | 
+--------------------+
```

```
+--------------------+
| InscribedStudent   | 
+--------------------+
| id                 | 
| student_id         | << Foreign key 
| classroom_id       | << Foreign key 
+--------------------+
```

```
+--------------------+
| SelectionProcess   | 
+--------------------+
| id                 | 
| classroom_id       | << Foreign key
| enabled            |
+--------------------+
```

```
+-------------------------+
| StudentSelectionProcess | 
+-------------------------+
| id                      | 
| inscribed_student_id    | << Foreign key
| selection_process_id    | << Foreign key
| status                  |
+-------------------------+
```

My QueryBuilder

```php
$student = DB::table('students')
            ->join('inscribed_students', 'inscribed_students.student_id', '=', 'students.id')
            ->join('classrooms', 'classrooms.id', '=', 'inscribed_students.classroom_id')
            ->join('selection_processes', 'selection_processes.classroom_id', '=', 'classrooms.id')
            // If exists show, else null
            ->leftjoin('student_selection_processes', 'student_selection_processes.selection_process_id', '=', 'selection_processes.id')
            ->select('students.*', 'classrooms.*', 'student_selection_processes.*')
            ->where([
                ['selection_processes.enabled', 1], // Very important
                ['students.id', $id]
            ])
            ->first();
```

But I consider the way very messy and still need to rearrange for the resource, so I want know if is possible to convert this **Query** to **Eloquent relationship**.

My expected eloquent json result

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "This is a Student",
  "email": "dborer@example.org",
  "enrolled": [
    {
      "id": 31,
      "name": "This is a Classroom",
      "shift": "Morning",
      "process: {
        "id": 5,
        "status": "Approved"   
      } 
    }
  ]
}
```

I can get at the classrooms but I don't know how can I get the process

```php
// StudentController.php - Student controller
$student = Student::with(['enrolled'])
           ->find($id);

// Student.php - Student Model
public function enrolled()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classroom', 'inscribed_students');
}
```

If possible, if student_selection_processes is null don't show the related classroom

Comment: Can you show your models and db design?

Comment: @DilipHirapara I updated with the model structure

Answer (score 1):

I am not fully understanding what you are after, however, something like this might help:

```
Student::with(['classroom', 'classroom.selectionProcess', 'classroom.selectionProcess.StudentSelectionProcess'])
    ->having(['classroom.selectionProcess.StudentSelectionProcess'])
    ->find($id);
```

Have a look at nested eager loading in Laravel Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

Model **Student**(table name)

```
//relation beetween student and classroom
public function StudentClassroom(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classroom','inscribed_student','student_id','classroom_id')->withTimestamps();
}

//relation beetween Student and InscribedStudent   
public function enrolled(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\InscribedStudent','student_id','id');
}
```

Model **Classroom** (table name)

```
//relation beetween classroom and student
public function classroomstudents(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student','inscribed_student','classroom_id','student_id')->withTimestamps();
}


//relation beetween classroom and SelectionProcess
public function selectionclass(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\SelectionProcess','classroom_id','id');
}
```

Model **SelectionProcess**(table name)

```
 //relation beetween SelectionProcess and InscribedStudent
public function SelectionProcesInscribedStudent(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\InscribedStudent','student_selection_process ','inscribed_student_id','selection_process_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

Model **InscribedStudent**(table name)

```
 //relation beetween InscribedStudent and SelectionProcess
public function InscribedStudentSelectionProces(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\SelectionProcess','student_selection_process ','selection_process_id','inscribed_student_id')->withTimestamps();
}

//relation beetween InscribedStudent and Student
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student','student_id','id');
}

//relation beetween InscribedStudent and classroom
public function classroom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\classroom','classroom_id','id');
}
```

Model **StudentSelectionProcess**(table name)

```
//relation beetween StudentSelectionProcess and InscribedStudent
public function inscribed_student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\InscribedStudent','inscribed_student_id','id');
}

//relation beetween StudentSelectionProcess and SelectionProcess
public function selection_process()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SelectionProcess','selection_process_id','id');
}
```

Now do in your controller

```
Student::with(['StudentClassroom','enrolled.InscribedStudentSelectionProces']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships

It's how I would do this. Rename the relationship to the one you will create in your model.

```
$student = Student::with(['manyToMany_classrooms_students.hasMany_selectionProcess' => function($query1) use($id) {
    $query1->where('enabled', 1);
    $query1->with(['hasMany_studentSelectionProcess' => function($query2) use($id) {
        $query2->where('student_id', $id);
    }])
}])->find($id);
```

I would also change your table for this

```
+--------------------+
| InscribedStudent   | 
+--------------------+
| //id               | << Remove id -> you don't need this for that situation
| student_id         |
| classroom_id       |
+--------------------+

+-------------------------+
| StudentSelectionProcess | 
+-------------------------+
| id                      |
| student_id              | << Refer directly to your student -> InscribedStudent is 
| selection_process_id    |           not a model, it's a pivot table
| status                  |
+-------------------------+
```

Using this, with correct relationship, you can find a user with StudentSelectionProcess. Join the SelectionProcess then the classroom.

```
Student -> hasMany -> StudentSelectionProcess -> belongsTo -> SelectionProcess -> belongsTo -> Classroom
```

Taking time to create relationships correctly will make your life easier.

Comment: All tables have at least 5 fields, I just summarized what is important to solve my problem. Make this changes will be not possible to solve the purpose of this project

Comment: Then don't change it and add the student_id to your StudentSelectionProcess?

Comment: My StudentSelectionProcess have a InscribedStudent, and InscribedStudent has the Student, so if i add the student_id will be appear a retain cicle

Comment: Yes and No, It will let you query data from StudentSelectionProcess table directly with your Student model instead of going through others models. If you want to show every status of  the StudentSelectionProcess to a student, you can get them using ```$student = Student::with('hasMany_studentSelectionProcess ')->find($id);```